# How would you index a table that is being initialized?

Tags: dictionary, lua, initialization, this

An example of what I desire:

```
local X = {["Alpha"] = 5, ["Beta"] = this.Alpha+3}

print(X.Beta) --> error: [string "stdin"]:1: attempt to index global 'this' (a nil value)
```

is there a way to get this working, or a substitute I can use without too much code bloat(I want it to look presentable, so fenv hacks are out of the picture)

if anyone wants to take a crack at lua, repl.it is a good testing webpage for quick scripts

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can't just set Beta on another line?

Comment: Yes, this is my specific use case: http://pastebin.com/Ysab8rNL

it is much more organized to use a table, instead of two lines, it would make the table itself obsolete

Comment: John please add the code in your question, it makes a difference to the answer, and some organizations (like my employer) block access to pastebin and other share sites (I saw code from home, but can't access from here). Also a post should be as self-contained as possible.

Answer (score 3):

No there is no way to do this because the table does not yet exist and there is no notion of "self" in Lua (except via syntactic sugar for table methods). You have to do it in two steps:

```
local X = {["Alpha"] = 5}
X["Beta"] = X.Alpha+3
```

Note that you only need the square brackets if your key is not a string or if it is a string with characters other than any of `[a-z][A-Z][0-9]_`.

```
local X = {Alpha = 5}
X.Beta = X.Alpha+3
```

Update:

Based on what I saw on your pastebin, you probably should do this slightly differently:

```
local Alpha = 5
local X = {
    Alpha = Alpha,
    Beta = Alpha+3, 
    Gamma = someFunction(Alpha), 
    Eta = Alpha:method()
}
```

(obviously Alpha has no method because in the example it is a number but you get the idea, just wanted to show if Alpha were an object).

Comment: For the sake of completeness of alternatives: `local alpha = 5 local X = {["Alpha"] = alpha, ["Beta"] = alpha+3}`

Comment: @TomBlodget Indeed, thanks. Based on the pastebin content that I saw after I posted, turns out this variable is closer to what OP probably should use.